# create a link to admin area

Tags: ee2, sessions, admin, links

I want to create a link from the font side of my site to the admin area.

The problem is the session id

```
<a href ="admin.php">go to admin</a>
```

This goes back to the login page even though I am logged in, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `{cp_session_id}` global variable to create a control panel link. See the documentation [here](http://www.ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#cp-session-id).

```
{if logged_in_group_id == "1"}
    <a href="{cp_url}?S={cp_session_id}">go to admin</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: Note above: the group ID number should be changed to whatever member group this is for.